# Infinite product and holomorphic function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I have trouble with a problem. The problem is as follows:

> Let $(a_n), (b_n)\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert a_n-b_n\lvert<\infty$. Consider
>   $F(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z-a_n}{z-b_n}$.
>
> 1. In which sets do we have uniform convergence of the product?
> 2. Where is $F$ holomorphic?

**My guess:**

I'm lost.

For (1.) I have tried to use a result which states that, for $0\leq u_n<1$, we have that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-u_n)>0$ ("converges" in some sense) if and only if $\sum^\infty_{n=1}u_n<\infty$. But how do I approach it with series?

And for the (2.), I think it has to be with the first.

Comment: With $\prod_n(1+ x_n)\text{ converges unconditionally}\iff\sum_nx_n\text{ converges unconditionally}$ and $$\frac{z-a_n}{z-b_n}-1=\frac{z-a_n-z+b_n}{z-b_n}=\frac{b_n-a_n}{z-b_n}$$ you find that your product will converge unconditionally for all $z$ such that $\frac1{z-b_n}$ is a bounded expression (but also for others). If for example the $b_n$ are localised in some Ball $B_r(b)$ then you have unconditional convergence for all $z\in\bigcap_n (\mathbb C-B_{r+1/n}(b))$.

Comment: As to holomorphicity, if you are doing a lecture you most likely had a theorem of the form: Let $f_n$ be holomorphic functions $\prod_n (1+f_n)$ is holomorphic on some neighbourhood of a $z$ if $\sum_n f_n$ converges uniformly on compacta in this neighbourhood. This would give in the previous case ($b_n$ localised in some ball) that $F$ is holomorphic on the same set as before.

Answer (score 2):

If the convergence is uniform then $F$ is holomorphic, as a uniform limit of holomorphic functions (except of course when $z = b_n$, where the function has a pole). So you need to show the uniform convergence at every $z \notin \{b_1, b_2, \dots \}$

Let's try with your criterion. $\frac{z - a_n}{z - b_n} = 1 - (1 - \frac{z - a_n}{z - b_n})$ and thus the serie converges (resp. converges uniformly) if and only if $\sum 1 - \frac{z - a_n}{z - b_n} = \sum \frac{a_n - b_n}{z - b_n}$ converges (resp. converges uniformly) .We can see that for any $z$ far from the $b_k$ we will have uniform convergence, since assuming $\sup |y - b_k| = \delta$ gives $| \sum \frac{a_n - b_n}{y - b_n}| < \frac{1}{\delta} \sum |a_n - b_n| $.

You will still have conditions on your $b_k$, for example if this is dense sequence in $\mathbb C$ the function will be not defined anywhere.